How to get iTunes “.exe” last update date in Windows?
I suspect a sync problem with my iPhone 7 might be due to a silent iTunes update (on Windows 10), so I need to check whether the iTunes .exe last change time correlates with the onset of the problem.
But the iTunes .exe is hidden away in ProgramFiles\WindowsApps, which is owned by Trusted Installer, and I can't get access to it even logged in as administrator.
Perhaps as administrator, I could take ownership. I'm not sure that would even work and even if it did, what would it break? If you take ownership of an object, does the original owner still retain his access? And if not, how would I restore ownership?

Just use Windows Store to check when the application was last updated, or uninstall it, and install the Win32 version of iTunes. Taking ownership of WindowsApps will break every UWP application installed on your system.

You could also go into greater detail to the synchronization issue you have. Perhaps we can help with that issue instead of the red herring issue of determining if iTunes was updated or not.

Unfortunately Windows Store tells me the installed verion (which I already know) but nothing about the install date, I might try he Win32 version in tthe hope it might work, but in uninstalling the current version I'd loose forever any chance of seeing whether its last update time corresponds to the tie the prblem appeared.

I'd love to go into more detail about the sync problem, but no error messages, nothing in the iTunes menus, and just failure to see my iPhone, I'm flailing in the dark. If I knew the problem started with the latest iTunes update I could just curse Apple, swallow hard and update my iPhone, and to hell with the carbon footprint!

The thing about iTunes is it's sort of a black box.  If Apple dropped support for iPhone 7 then both the Win32 and UWP application would be impacted.  If that were to have happen you would also be out of luck since Apple only supports the current version of iTunes. I would rule out the obvious things first before making that conclusion.  So, I would rule out the cable as the culprit. Does Windows detect the phone? In my experience if Windows is not asking how to handle the iPhone then it's not even attempt to communicate with it which means iTunes won't display it.

Thank you, yes, it is a black (and very murky) box. In my original post I did say that Windows can see it and photos on it, so the cable and lightning port are pretty well excluded. When I have a bit more time I'll see if I can see the exe using some form of sudo for Windows, or try installing it in a VM.

An UWP applications permissions cannot be elevated.

No, I don't want to elevate the UWP's permissions - I want to elevate my permissions so I can see it. If I could run as Tusted Installer I could do that.

If you change the permissions of the directory you will permanently break all UWP applications on your system. Windows Store will indicate when the application was last updated.

Someone tipped me off that OneCommander run as Administrator should be able to see inside Program Files\WindowsApps, and indeed it did. But it showed a date on October, well before the problem arose.
I tried a fresh install of iTunes on another Win10 system, and that could see my iPhone 7! So I uninstalled iTunes and everything Apple (except iCloud - I feared I might loose my iCloud calendar sync from Thunderbird Calendar) on my regular computer, rebooted, and reinstalled iTunes. Problem fixed!
But OneCommander was still reporting the same creation and modified date in October for iTunes.exe - evidently the build date not the installtion date, and iTunes was reporting the same version number.
Whether it was caused by an alpha particle in my RAM, alien influence, or plain old Murphy's Law I have no idea and unlikely in the extreme to ever know.
So for the sake of bots which down-vote me because they can't follow the explanation of the diagnostic process:
If Windows can see your iPhone by iTunes can't, it seems that uninstalling then reinstlling iTumes may well help.
Thank you to those who tried to help.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you download the iTunes setup file from Apple, then the default location of iTunes installation is: C:\Program Files\iTunes. In my case, I changed it to D drive during installation. You can see the date modified for itunes.exe from the root install folder.
P.S. I login as admin account.


This is only for the legacy iTunes application on Windows.  Apple replaced it with the UWP iTunes application more than 5 years ago. The author is asking about the UWP application.
